# How to implement the Amazon In-App Purchase API?

Tags: java, android

Hi sorry for the vague title. I have a specific issue with the Amazon IAP API that you will see in the bottom of the post.

I implemented the API in the simplest way possible, that is I just imported their sample IAP app and pasted all of it in my app. I think the only thing that needs to be changed from the sample app is the SKU and marketplace.

This is a class called *MySku.java* from the sample app:

```
package com.amazon.sample.iap.entitlement;

/**
 * 
 * MySku enum contains all In App Purchase products definition that the sample
 * app will use. The product definition includes two properties: "SKU" and
 * "Available Marketplace".
 * 
 */
public enum MySku {

    // The only entitlement product used in this sample app
    LEVEL2("com.amazon.sample.iap.entitlement.level2", "US");

    private final String sku;
    private final String availableMarkpetplace;

    /**
     * Returns the MySku object from the specified Sku and marketplace value.
     * 
     * @param sku
     * @param marketplace
     * @return
     */
    public static MySku fromSku(final String sku, final String marketplace) {
        if (LEVEL2.getSku().equals(sku) && (marketplace == null || LEVEL2.getAvailableMarketplace().equalsIgnoreCase(marketplace))) {
            return LEVEL2;
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the Sku string of the MySku object
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public String getSku() {
        return this.sku;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the Available Marketplace of the MySku object
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public String getAvailableMarketplace() {
        return this.availableMarkpetplace;
    }

    private MySku(final String sku, final String availableMarkpetplace) {
        this.sku = sku;
        this.availableMarkpetplace = availableMarkpetplace;
    }

}
```

So I have to change the `sku` and `availableMarketplace`. I know my in-app product's sku so I set it, but what do I change `availableMarketPlace` to so that my app allows all marketPlaces instead of just the US one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to declare each SKU for each availableMarkpetplace, like this>

```
LEVEL2("com.amazon.sample.iap.entitlement.level2", "US"),
    LEVEL2_MX("com.amazon.sample.iap.entitlement.level2", "MX");
```

And for the MySku function as follows>

```
public static MySku fromSku(final String sku, final String marketplace) {
        for (MySku mySku : values()) {
            if (mySku.getSku().equals(sku) &&
                    (null == marketplace || mySku.getAvailableMarketplace().equals(marketplace))) {
                return mySku;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Don Pec

Comment: Where do I get all the two letter codes for every amazon marketplace? Sorry I know it's a stupid question but since I'm putting random letters in there I have to be sure

Comment: According to Amazon it should be an ISO 2 letters specification (check this link> https://www.iban.com/country-codes), go to your Amazon Developer Console then on In-App Items you can see your product price for different countries for each marketplace,  that should be the countries where your product may be avaliable. Hope it helps.